# Is there any way to remove the fading animation on .onDelete SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

The code is below. I want to delete the final fading animation when `onDelete` is tapped.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var names = ["david", "john", "amber"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(names, id: \.self) { (item) in
                Text(item)
            }.onDelete(perform: self.deleteItem)
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItem(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
        self.names.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}
```

I tried to use `.animation()` but none works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to force redraw the `List`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var names = ["david", "john", "amber"]
    @State private var listId = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(names, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
        }
        .id(listId)
    }

    private func deleteItem(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
        names.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
        listId = UUID()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is there is no list and there is only forEach

Comment: @LearningLee You need to apply id to the parent container. It can be VStack, List etc.

Comment: Unfortunately i doesn't work on anything other than a list , for example Vstack. You can not even delete on Vstack . Thanks for your help