# How can i remove the trailing red animation at the end of swipe deleting using .onDelete swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uianimation, swiftui-animation

This is the code :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var names = ["A" , "B", "C", "D"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(names, id: \.self ) { name in
                Group {
                    testStruct(name: name)
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: removeItems)
        }
    }
    private func removeItems (indexSet: IndexSet) {
        names.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
}


struct testStruct: View , Identifiable {
    @State var name: String
    let id = UUID()
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
           Text(name)
           Spacer()
           Image(systemName: "folder.fill")
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to remove the trailing red animation on swiping onDelete . Is there any elegant way of doing that . .animation() seem not to be working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to remove the fading animation on .onDelete SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055582/is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-fading-animation-on-ondelete-swiftui)

Comment: No it does not . Suppose i remove the list or use any other parent container , it does not work

Comment: Instead of *suppose*, please add the relevant code. Otherwise it's just guessing. Note that you can only use `onDelete` in a `List`/`Form`.

Comment: @HumbleFool: I tested pawello2222 given link and code, it does handle issue much better than you are still facing but it does not disable animation totally I have to say, it is better than nothing.